# How to detect music note and chords programmatically (in iPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone

How to detect music note and chords programmatically (in iPhone SDK) ??

Answer (score 3):

You would need to do a Fourier transform (usually a FFT) of the incoming sound wave and find the dominant frequency, then look up that frequency in a table of notes with their corresponding frequencies.

FFT is part of iOS since iOS4 and is located in the Accelerate framework.

Look at this [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425504/iphone-cpu-power-to-do-dsp-fourier-transform-frequency-domain) for more info and sample code.

To detect a chord is done by the same principle, but it's much trickier, since you need to find all the notes that make up the chord.

Comment: i got the point, looks like to detect a single note, we can get it by freq. values, but how to detect chords (composed of multiple notes).

Comment: Well, you would simply need to pick out more notes by freq. values. If you do a fourier transform on a chord you will see all the dominant frequencies. Those are probably the notes you want. (But it will be tricky distinguishing them from overtones, esp. if you don't know the number of notes in the chord. Definitely doable, but not easy.)